# Decode video frame with PPS and SPS

Tags: windows

I got PPS and SPS manually from a MOV video file it exists in avcC headr.
SPS  = 27 6400 29 AC 1B 2B..........
PPS = 28 DE 09 8B
decoder is not able to decode video frame using int avcodec_decode_video2(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVFrame *picture,
                         int *got_picture_ptr,
                         const AVPacket *avpkt). This function gives got frame value 0 .
    Kindly tell me how to use SPS and PPS value to decode video frame. which parameter i have to set in this function for secusseffuly decoding

Answer (score 0):

How do you add SPS/PPS header to your frame ? if you add manually these header to your frame, you should add also 00 00 00 01 bytes between them. These values for h264 format. So your frame after adding header is gonne look like this :

00 00 00 01 (SPS) 00 00 00 01 (PPS) 00 00 00 01 (DATA)

good luck